# How to pass get parameter to same page and to process db query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am a complete newbie to wordpress plugin and I am working on custom wordpress plugin. I have custom plugin file named "contact_view.php"

File:contact_view.php
"filepath" is plugin folder
View:

```html
<td><a href='$filepath/contact_view.php?iq=1' >Empty </a></td>

Code:
<?php
if(isset($_GET['iq']))
{
global $wpdb;
$iq=$_GET['iq'];
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(" UPDATE wp_email SET FLAG=0 WHERE id = $iq ", $iq));
}
?>
```

Empty ;

when I click on href link the GET parameter should pass id to self page i.e. contact_view.php and perform database function using the id of same page.

But I get following error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object - means I need to include wordpress core function like wp-config.php to access $wpdb-query().

I have tried passing it to a new file name "contact_test.php" where I have to call wordpress core function to have wordpress access and to call $wpdb-query().

Kindly suggest any better idea or method to do the above.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Use the wp-ajax features to get access to Wordpress functions without dealing with things like page templates.  You don't actually have to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the wp-core in your file

`require_once('wp-load.php');`

Or whatever the location of your wp-load.php is (it's in the root).

Comment: You shouldn't include wp-load.  It isn't necessarily going to be in the root, and there's no way to reliably find it.  I usually use the wp-ajax functions to get around this